# How to fill list view in fragment activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to fill my list in a fragment but it return null object reference.(`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`)
There is my code:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        person.add(new Gender("35AE111", false, "60 km/h"));

        final ListView listview= (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.liste);

        CustomAdapter customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), kisiler);
        listview.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_vehicles, container, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your things that need the view into onCreateView:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    person.add(new Gender("35AE111", false, "60 km/h"));
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_vehicles, container, false);
    final ListView listview= (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.liste);

    CustomAdapter customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), kisiler);
    listview.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: It does not work it is a fragment there is a inflater below.
public class AllVehicles extends android.app.Fragment {
    final List<Gender> kisiler=new ArrayList<Gender>();
    public AllVehicles() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Fragment`'s view is not created yet in `onCreate` method. You should move your code from `onCreate` to `onCreateView`:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_vehicles, container, false);

    final ListView listview= (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.liste);

    CustomAdapter customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), kisiler);
    listview.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: @mesopotamia Please check if R.layout.fragment_all_vehicles really contains ListView with id == liste

Answer (score 0):

The exception arising because you are calling `findviewbyid(int)` in `onCreate()` and inflating layout in `onCreateView()`....!

The issue is that `onCreate()` method of a fragment calls first and after that onCreateView is called by the fragment life cycle...!

You should read the  [fragment's life cycle](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle)

Below code help you,

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_vehicles, container, false);
        person.add(new Gender("35AE111", false, "60 km/h"));

        final ListView listview= (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.liste);

        CustomAdapter customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), kisiler);
        listview.setAdapter(customAdapter);
return view;
    }
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The null ptr exception happened since onCreate() got called before onCreateView() and getView() in onCreate returned null. Try the below snippet. I have moved your code in onCreate() to onCreateView()

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all_vehicles, container, false);
    person.add(new Gender("35AE111", false, "60 km/h"));

    final ListView listview= (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.liste);

    CustomAdapter customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), kisiler);
    listview.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your view is inflated you can override onViewCreated

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    person.add(new Gender("35AE111", false, "60 km/h"));

    final ListView listview= (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.liste);

    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), kisiler);
    listview.setAdapter(customAdapter);
}
```

Also make sure that the listview id is correct in your XML, sometimes that is an issue.